# Generate random numbers between two numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, random

```
public class TestSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        double ran = Math.random();



    }
}
```

I don't want to use `Random r = new Random();` class. Is there any other way to generate random numbers. I am just struck with what logic could be applied to generate random numbers between two numbers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/java-generating-random-number-in-a-range

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to use Random class?

Comment: Don't want to use the `Random` class? Consider using this instead: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872138/is-there-good-prng-generating-values-without-hidden-state<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190135/open-source-random-number-generation-algorithm-in-c

Comment: random means it doesnt follow any logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using this code:

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
double ran = Math.random();
double random;

if(a < b)
    random = (b-a)*ran + a;
else
    random = (a-b)*ran + b;
```

This will work for `a >= 0 and b >= 0` if you consider using negative number the logic sligtly changes

Comment: +1: You don't need to check which is greater or whether they are positive. If `a` and `b` are say '1' and '5' you will get a random number between '1' and '5 or between '5' and '1' The result should be effectively the same.

Comment: yes, you right... because then the difference becom negative and get subtracred to the big one. feel lazy of testing the behaviour with negative numbers...:p

Answer (score 8):

It's really easy... you only need to figure out which is the minimum value and what is the difference between the two numbers (let's call it `diff`). Then, you can scale the Math.random value (between `0` and `1`) by multiplying by `diff` (now its range is between `0` and `diff`). Then, if you add the minimum value, your range is between `min` and `min + diff` (which is the other value)

```
int min = min(a,b);
int max = max(a,b);

int diff = max - min;

int result = min + diff * Math.random();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting a `double` result, the simplest approach is

```
int a =
int b =
double result = (a-b)*Math.random() + b;
```

It doesn't matter which is greater as you get the same distribution.

However, if you want a random integer between 'a' and 'b' is a bit more complex.

```
int a = 
int b =
int result = Math.floor((Math.abs(a-b)+1) * Math.random()) + Math.min(a, b);
```

The reason the result is different is that a random double between 0 and 1 will be just less than 1 i.e. [0.0, 1.0) However a random integer between 1 and 6 usually includes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 equally. As a decimal this is the round down of [0.0 ... 7.0)

Answer (score 0):

You may get white noise from your microphone, and take any number from there. After that you may take any number from the given data, and do with it what you want. The example of getting data from the microphone can be found [here](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/1579071/Java-Sound-Getting-Started-Part-2-Capture-Using-Specified-Mixer.htm).